# How to autofill number depending on next column and cell(number-1)?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am looking for a Google Sheets formula to autofill number depending on next column and cell(number-1) like this:

[image: requirement]

I've tried using `=if(ISBLANK(C11);"";ROW(B11)-8)` but the result is like:

[image: attempt]

What is the right formula?

Comment: Hello! Please can you give an example of your desired output.  The two pictures above are identical and, according to your post, not what you want.

Comment: @Paul compare the 2nd pic with the others, on the 2nd pick I have two **_7_** number that i want to make it **_6_** on first same number with formula

Comment: Got it - so you want a cumulative total of how many rows have been filled up so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
=IF(B1<>"";COUNTA(INDIRECT("B1:B"&row()));)
```

As in this image:
[image]

**Link to working copy**

[Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11eq53jTCTqzTkAllpZICz31Tc8TCMGUjUopeETDDdXc/edit#gid=0)

Is this what you where trying to do?